# increase all values in list by one

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have a multidimensional list. which is , list of integer list . now my requirement is if some condition occurs while processing this list . then what ever comes next to that processing value will have to be increased by 1.
eg :

```
L = new List of (list of int32)
L1 = new List of int32
L2 = new List of int32
L1 = {1,2,3}
L2 = {3,4,20}
L = {L1,L2}
```

now while processing  second element of L1 the condition occured. then it should be

```
 L1 = {1,2,4}
 L2 = {4,5,21}
```

so obviously L will be having updated lists now !

currently written code :

```
Dim L1 As New List(Of int32)({1,2,3})
Dim L2 As New List(Of int32)({4,5,20})
Dim L As New List(Of System.Collections.Generic.List(Of int32))
L.Add(L1)
L.Add(L2)
Dim Lis As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of int32)
Dim nn As Int32
Dim condition As Int32
condition = 1
Dim master As Int32
master = 0
Dim counter, counter1 As Int32
counter = 0
counter1 = 0

For Each Lis In L
    If counter >= master Then
        For Each nn In Lis
            If counter1 > condition Then
                //here Is what i need your help//
            End If
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
        Next
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Next

For Each Lis In L  
    For Each nn In Lis
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(nn.ToString)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Might need to explain things a little more.  Perhaps start with exactly what your difficulty is?

Comment: done :) i  think the problem is evident now. 
here i have hard coded the value of "condition" and "master"  . but in real those values will be coming from some where else. that will be the differnece.

Comment: Instead of `For Each nn In Lis`, use `For i = 0 to Lis.Count - 1`. Now, you can simply do `Lis(i) += 1` to increment the value.

Comment: in that help section i need to do something like

 L(counter(counter1) = L(counter(counter1) + 1

Comment: that worked. thanks  for that first of all. but is there a linq solution to this ? as we deal with collections there must be something .

Comment: @seetharaman The purpose of LINQ is to query data, not change it. If you are not creating brand new lists, you don't use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Techniques used:

- [Extension methods in VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-write-an-extension-method)

Alas, my VB is a bit rusty, I'll write it in C#. I guess you will be able to translate it to VB:

```
public static IList<IList<int>> ToIncrementedValues(
    this IList<IList<int>> source,
    Func<int, bool> condition)
{
    List<List<int>> returnValue = new List<List<int>();
    int incrementValue = 0;
    foreach (IList<int> innerList in source)
    {
        List<int> innerReturnValue = new List<int>();
        foreach (int i in innerList)
        {
             if (condition(i)
             {
                 // condition met; from now on, every value one higher:
                 incrementValue += 1;
             }
             innerReturnValue.Add(i + incrementValue); 
        }
        returnValue.Add(innerReturnValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<List<int>> values = ...
var result = values.ToIncrementedValues();
```